# Notation in mathematical equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  $$W_{max}(T)$$
     or
       $$W_{\mbox{max}}(T).$$    
      \end{document}
```

I ask if I should write `$W_{max}(T)$` of  `$W_{\mbox{max}}(T)$` or there are athers commands.

Thanks

Comment: `W_{\max}` is the idea.

Comment: You should *not* use `$$ ... $$` for display math in LaTeX though, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use `W_\max`. Another possibility is `W_{\text{max}}`.

Comment: Both should not be used. First should at least have braces (bit of a fluke that is works), `\text` should never (ever) be used like this. It will be italic if used in a context where the surrounding text is italic (for example in a theorem). It us better to use `\textup` or `\textnormal `

Comment: @daleif I understand (and agree with) your comment concerning the use of the `\text` command, but not the other one. What do you mean with “bit of a fluke”? It works, doesn't it?

Comment: Basic users does not understand why it works with this particular macro and not with the one they made them self, having to explain them the difference is IMO a waste of time, so promoting this use without braces should not be encouraged.

Comment: Try `$W_\notin$` to understand why it’s good practice to use braces.

Comment: When there exists text in mathematical equation like `$$......\mbox{and}......$$`. It is better to use `\mbox{}` or `\text{}`? Thank you

Comment: @Student `\text` is better. Check the difference between `\[\overbrace{A\times A\times\cdots\times A}^{n\text{ times}}\]`and what you get if you use `\mbox` instead.